# State updates but component does not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a task of adding implementation on a given website

There is a function of getting data (tickets) asynchronously and I need to allow a sorting option.
The sorting happens on the server side, and by a button click (of sorting type), the sorted data should be fetched and displayed again to the user.

My idea is this:

1. Get the sorted data on button click
2. Use setState() to set the new sorting type
3. This will call componentDidUpdate() and it will setState() to the new data asynchronously.
4. The last setState() should call render to display the data again

Everything works except for part 4 - The render function is being called but the data is not updated on the screen.
The class I am working on is this:

**App.tsx**

```
export type AppState = {
  tickets?: Ticket[];
  search: string;
  sortBy: string;
};

export class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, AppState> {
    
  state: AppState = {
    search: "",
    sortBy: "none",
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      tickets: await api.getTickets(this.state.sortBy),
    });    
  }

  renderTickets = (tickets: Ticket[]) => {
    /*
     * more stuff here
     */
    // log that verifies I am getting the sorted data
    console.log("Tickets in rednerTickets: ")
    {tickets.map((t)=>{
        console.log(t);
    })}

    return (
      <ul className="tickets" id="all_tickets">
        {tickets.map((ticket) => (
          <CustomTicket t={ticket}></CustomTicket>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };
  
  async componentDidUpdate(prevProp: AppState, prevState: AppState) {
    // if the sortBy state is different
    if (prevState.sortBy !== this.state.sortBy) {
      // perform getTickets and set the new tickets
      this.setState({
        tickets: await api.getTickets(this.state.sortBy),
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { tickets } = this.state;
    console.log("tickets in render: ", tickets);
    return (
      <main>
        <h1>Tickets List</h1>
        
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ sortBy: "date" });
          }}>Sort By Date
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ sortBy: "title" });
          }}>Sort By Title
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ sortBy: "email" });
          }}>Sort By Email
        </button>

        {/* Calls the function that renders the tickets */}
        {tickets ? this.renderTickets(tickets) : <h2>Loading..</h2>}
      </main>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

CustomTicket is another class component that gets ticket's data and displays it.

Note:

I tried to change componentDidUpdate to this:

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProp: AppState, prevState: AppState) {
    // if the sortBy state is different
    if (prevState.sortBy !== this.state.sortBy) {
        // perform getTickets and set the new tickets
      this.setState({
        tickets: await api.getTickets(this.state.sortBy),
      });
      // new line:
      ReactDOM.render(this.render(),document.getElementById('root'));
    }
  }
```

But it worked only for the first click, and it also came with "can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component" warning

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProp: AppState, prevState: AppState) {
  if (prevState.sortBy !== this.state.sortBy) {
    const tickets = await api.getTickets(this.state.sortBy)
    this.setState({
      tickets
    });
  }
}
```

In your implementation `setState` is calling and trying to take tickets, but tickets it is a Promise - not needed data.
First of first need to get tickets and then to call `setState`